# Delphi Form does not fire onActivate event when its parent is a TPanel

Tags: forms, delphi, events

When I click on the form's caption the OnActivate event is not fired. The reason is apparently that the form parent is a TPanel. The form is brought to front when clicking its caption but the onActivate event is not fired.
My solution was radical, I set the border style to bsnone and I created my own caption with a panel aligned to the top of the form. Then I use the mouse event on the panel to move the form. But I now have the problem how to resize the form without the border. Please help, thanks.

Comment: Get the parent form to notify you when the form is activated

Comment: Hello David. How do I do that?

Comment: I'd use a common base class for all forms in my program, and then override `Activate`. In that method, if the form has no parent, then I'd walk through the children and for any forms that are children, notify them. I'm assuming that the ultimate parent form receives the `OnActivate` event.

Comment: David I do not seem to understand your answer, or you my question. The problem is the form that is on the panel does not get the Activate event at all when it is activated. I have one main form and the other are children. The children have as parent a TPanel in the main form.

Comment: The form that has no parent, it receives `OnActivate` right?

Comment: yes, I think so. But I am not interested in that one, but in the others. I want to know which of the children is brought forth when I click on its caption.

Comment: Well, I am confused. When I have made one form be a child of a panel, then I have always filled the caption area. But you have child forms that you want to drag around inside another panel. You presumably have multiple forms inside one panel?

Comment: yes I do have multiple forms in one panel that i want to drag around

Comment: Hmm, there's lots more that is wrong. For instance, when you click on a child form,  it doesn't do anything with input focus. I suspect that there are simply loads of issues like this.

Comment: It seems to me you should use MDI forms instead of TPanel parented normal ones.

Comment: mdi forms do not work as I wish in my project